# OpenGL Android App works on most phones but textures come up white on Xoom

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

My Android app has been out for several months and works fine on any number of WVGA phones like the Droid, Droid 2, Galaxy, etc.

On the Motorola Xoom, however, a small portion of the textures load with white boxes where the images should be.

Researching online the most usual cause for this appears to be not using power of two textures.  This seems an unlikely explanation since they work fine on so many other devices.  Also, I *am* using power of two textures. The one caveat there is that I'm loading a bunch of bitmaps into a 1024 by 1024 texture dynamically.  The code I'm using is from a now defunct library called Rokon, the relevant texture atlas code is here: http://code.google.com/p/rokon/source/browse/trunk/src/com/stickycoding/rokon/TextureAtlas.java?r=260 -- Like I said, I'm skeptical this could be the cause since it works on so many other devices AND many of the textures I am loading this way do work fine.

But I'm not sure what else could be causing it.  A memory issue seems unlikely given that amount of memory available on the Xoom compared to the other devices the app works on.

Right now I don't own a zoom, but I can replicate the issue via DeviceAnywhere (where I see white backgrounds).

Nothing of interest shows up in LogCat either.

I know this isn't much to go on, but I'm at a loss here, what kinds of potential causes should I be looking at here?  Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Try using glGetError() to see if OpenGL throws any errors

Answer (score 1):

Is your application 2D or 3D? When you're drawing your sprites on the screen; which method are you using?

If your texture is white during `onDrawFrame` that probably depends on:

- An *untextured* quad (using VBO:s or standard Vertex Arrays) - *probably not, because it works on other devices*
- Xoom lacks support of the `draw_texture` extension - *if you're using 2D*
- Xoom lacks support of VBO:s (Vertex Buffer Objects) - *probably not, almost every Android device out there supports VBO:s*
- Do you have any sort of texture compression implemented that Xoom doesn't support?

At runtime, use this code to get the extensions and check if they're available:

```
String extensions = gl.glGetString(GL10.GL_EXTENSIONS);
boolean supportsDrawTexture = extensions.contains("GL_OES_draw_texture");
// Continue here and sooner or later you should see where Xoom lacks support 
// where other devices doesn't.
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you're falling foul of Android's automatically-resize-bitmaps behaviour? Print out the bitmap sizes as they are loaded to check, or move them to [res/drawable-nodpi](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers) to avoid the behaviour entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your texture exceeds 2048 pixels width or height? That's the maximum allowed texture size on XOOM.